# How can I get access to packet CMSG fields from Golang?

Tags: go, ip

I'm working on a Go program that receives packets and wants to see receipt timestamps.

In C this would be done by setting the SO_TIMESTAMP/SO_TIMETAMPNS socket option and then using the CMSG macros to extract data from a control message buffer structure,

I have searched the Go documentation for a way to do this, in vain.  Can anyone point me art a working example?

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/internal/socket#ControlMessage

Answer (score 0):

You can get them from UDPConn::ReadMsgUDP, the ancillary data was named "oob" for some weird reason, but it is the ancillary channel with the control messages.

You can parse the []byte with the control message data using x/sys/unix::Cmsghdr (https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/unix#Cmsghdr)

There should be a better way, but at least this is not behind "internal"...

Comment: @Yunnosch : thanks.  I actually found half-of-an-answer, which should at least point people in the right direction (including me), so there is no need to delete it anymore.

Comment: I cannot judge the technical details/correctness (which is also why I do not vote). But yes, now it reads like enough of an answer to let it be. Good way to take my feedback by the way. Have fun.